# Which software can I use to make graphs of my computer's temperature?

Tags: monitoring, temperature

I have bought a new fan for my PC and I want to try different configurations (air in/out) for the fans.

To measure the temperature I have AIDA64 Extreme, but the problem is that the values change easily and quickly, so using Print Screen to save the temperatures doesn't work very well.

Then, it would be great to have a program which draws the temperatures in a temperature/time graph.

Of course the program should measure CPU's temperature, but I would appreciate motherboard's and hard disks' one too.

Moreover, I have a DualCore AMD Athlon processor, and it seems that "*there is only one temperature sensor per CPU (not one per core)*" [<sub>1</sub>](http://help.argusmonitor.com/index.html?TemperaturemeasurementforAMDCPUs.html), but AIDA64 shows three temperatures (CPU, core1 and core 2). So it would be better a software designed to target AMD processors.

And it should be free. Am I asking too much?

Comment: @BradPatton Thanks for the link, I had heard about SpeedFan but I didn't know that it monitors temperatures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) to view the CPU (per core), Hard Drive and Motherboard Temperatures over time. It also includes a whole bunch of other information and is free for personal use. To get a graph go to the section you want and click on the little green grid by the temperature. Happy Graphing!

[image]
[image]

Comment: I am trying free version bot not seeing graphs anywhere. Is graph not there in free version?

Comment: As David said, click the green icons to show charts.

Comment: The graphs would be a lot more helpful if they labeled the axes.

Comment: OMG there is no scales in this graph! That stinks.

Comment: It's missing time labels on the X scale :(